# how to use python modules in a next js wetsite

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, next.js13

In this question, I want to know if it is possible to use python modules in a website that uses react and next js. For instance if I want to use a python algorithm that filter audio or images or applies a specific set on modifications on these resources how do you go about doing this?
I have tried using a get api, but i don't know how to send the file and then retrieve it back after the modification.

You may find bellow some of my attempts though they don't hold much significance to my question:

The route.js

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { exec } from "child_process";


export async function POST(request) {
  const { text } = await request.json();

  exec(`activate && python audio_processing.py ${text} && echo ${text}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
      return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
      console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  });

  return NextResponse.json({ product: text });
}
```

The app.js

```js
"use client";
import React from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import "./new.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";

export default function Sus() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [audioSrc, setAudioSrc] = React.useState(null);
  const [tank, nottank] = React.useState(null);

  const FileUploader = () => {
    const [isAudioFile, setIsAudioFile] = React.useState(false);

    const onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
      // Handle the uploaded files here
      console.log("hy:", acceptedFiles);

      const audioFile = acceptedFiles.find((file) =>
        file.type.startsWith("audio/")
      );
      if (audioFile) {
        // If an audio file is uploaded, set the audio source and mark it as an audio file
        setIsAudioFile(true);
        setAudioSrc(URL.createObjectURL(audioFile));
        console.log("this is the src:", audioFile);
      } else {
        setIsAudioFile(false);
        setAudioSrc(null);
      }
      nottank(audioFile);
    };

    const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

    return (
      <div>
        <div {...getRootProps()} className="dropzone">
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          <p>Drag & drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
        </div>

        {isAudioFile && audioSrc && (
          <div>
            <audio controls>
              <source src={audioSrc} type="audio/mpeg" />
              Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const postData = {text: tank };
  console.log('tank is:',tank)

  if (audioSrc !== null) {
    fetch("/point", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!file) return

    try {
      const data = new FormData()
      data.set('file', file)

      const res = await fetch('/api/nod', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      })
      // handle the error
      if (!res.ok) throw new Error(await res.text())
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle errors here
      console.error(e)
    }
  }



  return (
    <main>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello there</h1>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input
        type="file"
        name="file"
        onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files?.[0])}
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

The audio_processing.py

```py
import sys
from glob import glob
import librosa
import soundfile as sf

path = sys.argv[1]

print('pup is:',path)

y, sr = librosa.load(path) # this type of path works does detect the file path 

# add some modification but didn't have any idea about how to download the file in the browser for the user
```

Comment: You could write a Python script and your server-side JavaScript code could [invoke that script](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) as an external process.  It's not clear to me how "a get api" (I assume you mean an AJAX operation from the client to the server) is involved.  Anything using Python would be entirely server-side.

Comment: Can you give more details. Do you have a python function/class that takes in a file and returns processed output ? And you have tried wrapping that under a GET api to interact with it externally from your next app ?

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank you for your time and answers. Concerning the script I used and the api thing, I really didn't have any idea about what I was doing exactly and i just thought to myself that if an api could connect two pieces of an app together perhaps it is the right solution. but to be more specific what i wanted to understand is how the website that use file modification like image compression, pdf trimming, voice filtering and so on.
is all this done through just plain js and jlibraries or can they make you use of the different programming languages and if so how is it done

Comment: and if you are curious about the dumpster of code that I used I have added it to this question.

Comment: @youssefhafidi: Any given website could use any variety of languages and tools for server-side functionality.  If you're asking whether JavaScript code can interact with Python code directly then the answer is generally no.  But that doesn't mean a web application can't be written in Python, or that a web application can't communicate with another application on the server, or on another server, or through the command line, etc.  The specifics of what you would need to do depend on the specifics of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @David Technically there's a huge variety of languages for the client side now. WASM is nice.